# Explanation of python code snippet >>numpy.nonzero(row == max(row))[0][0]<< from a script using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

What does this peace of python code

```
row = R[i,]
j = numpy.nonzero(row == max(row))[0][0]
```

do, assuming this output:

```
command   # output of python
----------------------------------
R.shape   # (224, 24)
type(R)   # <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
type(row) # <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
type(j)   # <type 'numpy.int64'>
```

(I'll provide more information if required, to answer my question.)

### Update:

Sorry, I used two times the variable `i`. I changed that in the question!

Comment: @Emmet: Thank you very much for this detailed example. Now I got it!

Comment: @Aufwind er, oops, the example was actually posted by [eat](http://stackoverflow.com/users/579145/eat), which I mistook as an attempted edit by you (my bad). Lemme roll back my changes..

Comment: @Emmet: Seeing now OP's positive reaction to the example, which you literately copied from my answer and then deleted it, do you feel that you are acting along according the spirit of So?

Comment: @Aufwind: Please note that example was my answer which Emmet copied and the deleted my answer. Thanks

Comment: @Emmet: Care to elaborate more on why you copied my answer and then deleted it? Especially when my answer indeed seems to be helpful for the OP?

Comment: @Emmet and @eat: Well, this was a little confusing. When I came the first time online to see the answer, I saw three answers. An hour ago, when I came back to "accept and thank", there was only one answer, and an explanation added to my question as an edit. I didn't know what happened since then. An hour ago there was only one answer and that got **7** *voteups*. So I accepted this one and thanked for the edit. There was not more, that I could have done. @eat: Since your answer is back, I will accept it, of course. Sorry for confusion, but it was not my fault. :)

Comment: @Aufwind: I understand, it's definitely not your fault ;). If Emmet is willing to response, perhaps we'll find out what went wrong. Anyway, most importantly your original question get some substantial answers. Thanks

Comment: @eat My comment above explains what happened, but since you still seem confused, I'll explain it again: I didn't double-check Space_C0wb0y's original assessment, so I thought your answer should have actually been a question edit by Aufwind. So I deleted your answer and added it as an edit to the question. After realizing the mistake, I reverted the change.

Comment: @Emmet: Just for the record: You acted after I pointed the issue. But nothing personal, I'm only trying to figure out the SO protocol in these kind of cases. Anyway http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ is better place to continue discussion on cases like this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps an example will help:

```
In []: R= arange(12).reshape(4, 3)
In []: R
Out[]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])
In []: i= 1
In []: row= R[i, ]
In []: row
Out[]: array([3, 4, 5])
In []: j= nonzero(row== max(row))[0][0]
In []: j
Out[]: 2
```

Thus the `j` is the index of the maximum element in the `i`th row of `R`. So

```
In []: R[i, j]
Out[]: 5
```

Comment: Now, everything seems back to normal. ;-)

Answer (score 8):

The two lines appear to be a roundabout way of saying `j = np.argmax(R[i])`, i.e. find the column index of the largest element in the `i`-th row of `R`, and store the result in `j`.